# I can't inlude image in mail content using PHP

Tags: php

I cant include image in mail content using PHP.My code is give below.

```
 $message.='<td width="491" height="39"><img src="logo.png"></td>
<td width="482" height="48"><br />';
```

Any solution for these issue?

Comment: your image should be hosted somewhere. You can't just look for "logo.png", else the server will search it in its folder and most likely won't find it because, of course, it shouldn't be there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the absolute path to the image, so for instance `http://somesite.com/img/logo.png`.
Also your img should not be hosted on localhost, as only you would be able to see the image